# How to slice arrays in a for loop with the slicing indices variable

Tags: python, arrays, object-slicing

I want to slice an array of 64 items in eight parts and for that used the following method but it displayed a syntax error

```
for i in range(8):
    s = slice(8i,(8i+7))
    inparr = cornersort[s]
```

and

```
for i in range(8):
    inparr = cornersort[8i,(8i+7)]
```

Both show the Error message:

```
 s = slice(8i,(8i+7))
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However when I removed the for loop iterable 'i'; the code worked. Please help how to fix this.

Comment: `8i` is neither a valid number nor a valid variable name.

Comment: It’s not clear what your intention is. Do you want eight times `i`? That would be `8 * i`

Comment: @MarkMeyer looks that way: "I want to slice an array of 64 items in eight parts"

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am a beginner programmer and made this very silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `8i` is a valid mathematical expression, it is not a valid python statement, since the multiplication operation needs to be explicit, not implied:

```py
i = 8

8i # SyntaxError

8*i
64
```

Furthermore, in variable names, they must not start with a number:

```py
2i = 5
# syntaxError

i2 = 5
# this is fine
```

So for your loop:

```py
for i in range(8):
    inparr = cornersort[8*i:(8*i+8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below examples how to slice an array with 64 items into 8 slices of 8 items each. Please note the basic syntax `[start:stop]` and the slice indices are start <= i < stop, i.e. stop points one item after the slice.

```
test = list(range(64))

# example 1
for i in range(8):
    print(test[8*i:8*i+8])

# example 2
for i in range(0,64,8):
    print(test[i:i+8])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range`

```
 for i in range(0, 64, 8):
      # slice arr[i: i + 8]
```

the result is

```
i, i+8
0 8
8 16
16 24
24 32
32 40
40 48
48 56
56 64
```